# Choose an AST representation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, type-systems

I am currently working on a toy functional language compiler, with the purpose of learning type-related things and slightly advanced techniques in Haskell.

I believe I need to attach info to each node on my tree, like position in the original source code for better error reporting, type inferred, type constraints generated, etc. So initially I chose this method:

```
data Expr a = ELam [Pat a]  (Expr a) a
            | ELet [Decl a] (Expr a) a
            | EIf  (Expr a) (Expr a) (Expr a) a
            | ECase (Expr a) [Alt a] a
            | EApp (Expr a) [Expr a] a
            | EVar Variable a
            | ECon Variable a
            | ELit Literal  a
            | ELOpSec (Op a) (Expr a) a
            | EROpSec (Op a) (Expr a) a
            | EInfix  (Expr a) (Op a) (Expr a) a
            | ENeg    (Expr a) a
-- Intermediate representation, removed after resolving infix expressions.
            | EParen  (Expr a) a
            deriving (Eq, Show, Functor, Generic1)
```

`Functor` is derived for effectively transforming node attached, while `Generic1` allows a generic function to get that information out.

However, after I have finished the parser, I found the structure is a bit unfriendly for future-processing. Essentially I want a two layer structure, as the one mentioned [here](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/05/the-ast-typing-problem/). Something I am trying:

```
data Expr w = ELam  [w (Pat w)]  (w (Expr w))
            | ELet  [w (Decl w)] (w (Expr w))
            | EIf   (w (Expr w)) (w (Expr w)) (w (Expr w))
            | ECase (w (Expr w)) [w (Alt w)]
            | EApp  (w (Expr w)) [w (Expr w)]
            | EVar  (w Var)
            | ECon  (w Var)
            | ELit  (w Lit)
            | ELOpSec (w Var) (w (Expr w))
            | EROpSec (w Var) (w (Expr w))
            | EInfix  (w (Expr w)) (w Var) (w (Expr w))
            | ENeg    (w (Expr w))
```

The initial motivation is for more convenient/beautiful pattern matching, as the unnecessary information can be separated out. Besides, I have just read a [gentle introduction to recursion scheme](http://blog.sumtypeofway.com/an-introduction-to-recursion-schemes/) so I hope I could take advantages of existing library.

However, the above code I was trying was rejected by GHC. More precisely, I can not use it to derive `Eq` instance automatically. I tried a complicated standalone derivation:

```
deriving instance (Eq (a b))   => Eq   (Expr a)
```

But it is rejected after enabling several fancy extensions. I noticed the `recursion-scheme` library has the following code:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))

deriving instance Eq (f (Fix f)) => Eq (Fix f)
```

But I couldn't understand the instance—how are we gonna satisfy `Eq (f (Fix f))`?

I noticed that in the ezyang's blog addressing AST typing approaches, he used:

```
data ExpF a = Num Int
            | Bool Bool
            | Var Var
            | If a a a
            | Lambda Var a
            | App a a
newtype Exp = Exp (ExpF Exp)
newtype TExp = TExp (ExpF TExp, Type)
```

But I have different types of node inside `Expr`, e.g. patterns and declarations.

My question are:

1. Is there a way to use a two-layer type structure to express my AST? How can I derive `Eq` and `Show` instances?
2. From a long term of view, is it better to just stick with my original old plain AST types?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1kzwlg/ideas_for_annotating_an_ast_with_custom_data/ just for reference

Comment: The `Show` and `Eq` instances for `Fix` are counter-intuitive for sure. They work via mutual recursion with the instances for the functor `f` being `Fix`ed. Since your type incorporates `Fix`-style recursion you'll need to use some similar.

Answer (score 3):

An `Eq` instance for `Expr w` is fortunately fairly straightforward to write. When writing an `Eq` instance we'd normally ask for an `Eq` instance for all of the types used in the data type. For example, if we were going to write an `Eq` instance for

```
data E a b = A a
           | B b
```

We'd ask for a way to compare `a`s and `b`s

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (E a b)
```

If a type is higher kinded ...

```
data E w = EA (w A)
         | EB (w B)
```

... we still ask for a way to compare each of the types that occurred anywhere in `E`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

deriving instance (Eq (w A), Eq (w B)) => Eq (E a b)
```

The same thing can be done recursively, begging for a way to compare the inner types when deriving how to compare the data type. Recursive constraints require `UndecidableInstances`, in addition to the extensions used above.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data E w = EA (w A)
         | EB (w B)
         | EE (w (E w))

deriving instance (Eq (w A), Eq (w B), Eq (w (E w))) => Eq (E a b)
```

This is also what the recursion-schemes code for `Fix` is doing, but the only type used in `Fix` is `f (Fix f)`, so the constraint looks kind of magical.

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))

deriving instance Eq (f (Fix f)) => Eq (Fix f)
```

An `Eq` instance for `Expr w` is written the same way. The constraint asks for a way to compare each of the types that occurs in `Expr w`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

deriving instance (
    Eq (w (Pat w)),
    Eq (w (Decl w)),
    Eq (w (Alt w)),
    Eq (w Var),
    Eq (w Lit),
    Eq (w (Expr w))) => Eq (Expr w)
```

#### Models

The data type `Expr w` has the somewhat unusual kind `(* -> *) -> *`, which I call a **Model**. It is the kind of things that, given a **Functor** or **Monad**, which both have kind `* -> *`, produces a data type (which has kind `*`). An `Expr Identity` is an exact model of an expression. An `Expr IO` could model an expression whose value is constructed by interaction with the outside world. An `Expr ref` could model an `Expr` distributed over multiple machines, where the `ref` type describes where to go to get the other components, like an identifier to a database record. An `Expr Proxy` is just the constructors of an `Expr`, without any of the data. You are probably looking for something like the `Expr ((,) a)` which models an expression with an annotation of type `a` at each component.

You're actually probably looking for `(,) a (Expr ((,) a))`, which has an annotation for the entire structure as well as for each of its components. This looks a bit too much like garbage. To clean it up, we'll add a type synonym for data models that are in some functor.

```
type In f d = f (d f)
```

One possible type for an expression read from source is the expression annotated with the line number and column where each component is from.

```
type SourcePos = (Int, Int)
type SourceExpr = In ((,) SourcePos) Expr
```

I'm going to make some examples of `SourceExpr` by hand to check that the derived `Eq` instance works.

```
example1 :: SourceExpr  
-- if Var then Con else Lit
example1 = ((1, 1) , EIf ((1, 4), EVar ((1, 4) , Var)) ((1, 7) , ECon ((1, 12) , Var)) ((1, 16) , ELit ((1, 12) , Lit)))

example2 :: SourceExpr
-- if Var then Lit else Con
example2 = ((1, 1) , EIf ((1, 4) , EVar ((1, 4) , Var)) ((1, 7) , ELit ((1, 12) , Lit)) ((1, 16) , ECon ((1, 12) , Var)))

example3 :: SourceExpr
-- if Var
-- then Con
-- else Lit
example3 = ((1, 1) , EIf ((1, 4) , EVar ((1, 4) , Var)) ((2, 1) , ECon ((2, 6) , Var)) ((3, 1) , ELit ((3, 6) , Lit)))
```

For testing, I also made data types for `Pat` et. al., each with a single eponymous constructor. The dervied `Eq` instance works satisfactorily.

```
main = do
    print $ example1 == example1
    print $ example1 == example2
    print $ example1 == example3
    print $ example2 == example2
    print $ example2 == example3
    print $ example3 == example3
```

#### Onward

> From a long term of view, is it better to just stick with my original old plain AST types?

There isn't much existing Haskell support for working with models or data types with the kind `(* -> *) -> *`. If you start working with them the first thing you'll want is a class for data models `d` that are functors that map some natural transformation `(forall a. f a -> g a) -> d f -> d g`. You'd use this for example to remove the annotations from a source expression. The next thing you'll want is a lens-style uniplate library for data models, and any `Applicative`-like tools needed to support it.

You would be straying into the less-well-known. There are a couple ways to come back, but I haven't completely thought through either of them.

If you don't like the `UndecidableInstances` requirement for derived instances for `Expr` you could remove the explicit recursion, and add an argument for the model used for recursive occurrences of `Expr`. This would be compatible with a `PolyKinded` version of [`MMorph`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor).

```
data Expr w e = ELam  [w (Pat w)]  (w (e w))
              | ELet  [w (Decl w)] (w (e w))
              | EIf   (w (e w)) (w (e w)) (w (e w))
              | ECase (w (e w)) [w (Alt w)]
              | EApp  (w (e w)) [w (e w)]
              | EVar  (w Var)
              | ECon  (w Var)
              | ELit  (w Lit)
              | ELOpSec (w Var) (w (e w))
              | EROpSec (w Var) (w (e w))
              | EInfix  (w (e w)) (w Var) (w (e w))
              | ENeg    (w (e w))
```

The type `e` only ever appears in the type `e w`, which has kind `*`. If we replace `e w` with `a`, it suggests another slightly more generic type that is more in line with the types that have good existing library support. This `Expr` has kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)` which is much more common; it is the kind of monad transformers.

```
data Expr w a = ELam  [w (Pat w)]  (w a)
              | ELet  [w (Decl w)] (w a)
              | EIf   (w a) (w a) (w a)
              | ECase (w a) [w (Alt w)]
              | EApp  (w a) [w a]
              | EVar  (w Var)
              | ECon  (w Var)
              | ELit  (w Lit)
              | ELOpSec (w Var) (w a)
              | EROpSec (w Var) (w a)
              | EInfix  (w a) (w Var) (w a)
              | ENeg    (w a)
```

Either way you'd probably still be wanting a lens-style uniplate library compatible with your `Expr`s.

Comment: 1. Eq (f (Fix f)) => Eq (Fix f). The deriving itself is indeed straightforward, but how is its premise (Eq (f (Fix f)) satisfied? To me, it looks like a dead loop… Is this somehow related to UndecidableInstances? Could you try to expand it? First, we have a == b where a, b :: Fix Sth, then…I am stuck.

Comment: By the way, thank you for such a well-organized answer. However, I guess I need some time to experiment/digest it…so more questions on the way

Answer (score 1):

I asked an almost identical question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3sm1j1/how_to_mix_the_base_functorrecursion_scheme_stuff/), except for the emphasis on how to apply recursion scheme to mutually recursive data types. Redditor [/u/AndrasKovacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3sm1j1/how_to_mix_the_base_functorrecursion_scheme_stuff/cwyr61h) pointed out that I can use indexed type families and GADTs to reduce the problem to the ordinary situation:

```
data AstIx = AstDecl | AstExpr | AstPatt | AstType

type AstDecl = 'AstDecl
-- ...

data AstIxProxy (i :: AstIx) where
  DeclProxy :: AstIxProxy AstDecl
  -- ...

newtype AnnotAstF a f i = Annot { unAnnot :: (a, AstF f i) }

data AstF (f :: AstIx -> *) (i :: AstIx) where
  VarF   :: Var -> AstIxProxy i -> AstF f i
  LitF   :: Lit -> AstF f AstExpr
  -- ...
  IfF    :: f AstExpr -> f AstExpr -> f AstExpr -> AstF f AstExpr
  LamF   :: [f AstPatt] -> f AstExpr -> AstF f AstExpr
  LetF   :: [f AstDecl] -> f AstExpr -> AstF f AstExpr
  -- ...
```

For such data type, the old plain fixed point can be used:

```
newtype IxFix f i = In { out :: f (IxFix f) i }
```

Then, one just needs to define the indexed functor as well as other indexed type classes in order to take the advantage of recursion scheme. He also provided an [prototype example](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/af856be6cf816e08da95). [The original post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3sm1j1/how_to_mix_the_base_functorrecursion_scheme_stuff/cwyr61h) explains things clearly.

After that, I was thinking about the model thing as mentioned by @Cirdec. The most convenient solution to incorporate both things (recursion scheme and annotation on each node) is very clear, but I just couldn’t figure out. So I defined a fixed point with direct support for annotation, or “model” as @Cirdec mentioned in his answer:

```
newtype Fix w f = In { out :: w (f (Fix w f)) }
```

The AST became a three-layer structure, one for the fixed point wrapper, one for the model `w`, and one for the actual node. But the whole recursion scheme things cannot be built upon this fixed point.

Luckily, I realized that since I could give any type to `f`, the parameter of `AstF`, why couldn’t I encode the annotation there, too, like this?

```
newtype AnnotAstF a f i = Annot { unAnnot :: (a, AstF f i) }
```

`IxTraversable`, based on the one for `AstF`:

```
instance IxTraversable (AnnotAstF x) where
  itraverse f (Annot (x, t)) = (Annot . (x,)) <$> itraverse f t
```

Other operations, like removing annotations, can then be easily defined over recursion scheme primitives:

```
removeAnnot :: IxFix (AnnotAstF a) i -> IxFix AstF i
removeAnnot = cata (In . snd . unAnnot)
```

I just finished a prototype [Syntax.hs](https://github.com/notcome/indescript/blob/70bac101c7bb8b912decc5a5aff585fab3bf428b/src/Language/Indescript/Syntax.hs) but I believe such elegance is what I am looking for. May the Force be with me! : )

Thank you guys.